# Stable random variable with bounded values

Tags: probability-distributions

Recently I've came across "[Stable distributions](http://fs2.american.edu/jpnolan/www/stable/chap1.pdf)" and have seen ways of generating them.
I am interested in the so-called "p-stable" distributions (e.g. see [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/indyk/emnlp.pdf)), i.e. those such that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are copies of a random variable $\zeta,$ then for any constants $a_1,a_2 > 0$ ones has
that $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2$ has the distribution of $(a_1^p+a_2^p)^{1/p}\zeta.$
Here, $p > 0$ is a certain constant.
Would anyone enlighten me as to whether there exists a random variable $\zeta$ whose distribution is stable and whose values always lie in $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with support $(0,1)$, then $X_1+X_2$ have support $(0,2)$ while $(1+1)^{1/p}X_1$ have support $(0,2^{1/p})$. This means that the only suitable candidate for $p$ is $p=1$.

However if we suppose (towards a contradiction), that there exists a $1$-stable distribution on $(0,1)$ and consider two independent variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with this distribution, then we have that
$$Var(X_1 + X_2) = 2 Var(X_1)$$
while
$$Var(2X_1) = 4 Var(X_1)$$
implying that $2Var(X_1)=4Var(X_1)$, which is of course a contradiction unless $Var(X_1)=0$, which would imply that the distribution is degenerate.

Actually one can show that for stable distributions with $p\in (0,2)$ the variance is undefined and that the mean is also undefined if $p\in (0,1]$. But such distributions are necessarily unbounded.